# CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION what these parameters mean?

Tags: c++, libcurl

In `libcurl`, what the parameters mean in the function called by setting `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION`?

```
int function(void *clientp, double dltotal, double dlnow, double ultotal, double ulnow);
```

Its a lame question I know but the website doesn't seem to describe, or I wasn't able to find :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curlgtk.html) might help. To summarize:

```
int function(
  void *clientp,  // this is an unchanged pointer as set with CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA
  double dltotal, // the total bytes to be downloaded (or 0 if not downloading)
  double dlnow,   // the current download bytecount (or 0 if not downloading)
  double ultotal, // the total bytes to be uploaded (or 0 if not uploading)
  double ulnow);  // the current upload bytecount (or 0 if not uploading)
```

See [CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPROGRESSDATA) for `clientp`.
If you return any value other than 0 from the callback, the transfer will be cancelled.