# php cURL progress function size limit

Tags: php, curl, download, progress

I'm downloading a file using cURL 7.38.0 with php 5.6 and I'd like to get the download progress. This is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://path/to/file.zip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 65536);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'downloadProgress'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

function downloadProgress ($resource, $download_size, $downloaded_size, $upload_size, $uploaded_size) {
    echo 'download_size: ' . $download_size . '; downloaded_size: ' . $downloaded_size . ';<br>';
}
```

Everything works fine most of the time except that if the file is bigger than 2GB, then `$download_size` returns `-2147483648` and `$downloaded_size` works until it gets to `2147483648` and also turns to `-2147483648` and stops incrementing.

The output with a 3.4GB file is the following:

```
download_size: 0; downloaded_size: 0;
download_size: -2147483648; downloaded_size: 1147;
download_size: -2147483648; downloaded_size: 1147;
download_size: -2147483648; downloaded_size: 16987;
download_size: -2147483648; downloaded_size: 16987;
download_size: -2147483648; downloaded_size: 25627;
...
download_size: -2147483648; downloaded_size: -2147483648;
download_size: -2147483648; downloaded_size: -2147483648;
download_size: -2147483648; downloaded_size: -2147483648;
```

Is there something I have done wrong or is it a php cURL limitation?

Thank you.

Comment: Place the whole code for the `downloadProgress()` function, this most probably means that the variable, which stores the download size is an regular `signed integer`, i.e. from 2^32 to -2^32, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657630/curlopt-progressfunction-what-these-parameters-mean and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417507/in-my-curl-curlopt-progressfunction-callback-dltotal-is-always-0 on similar issues

Comment: Looks like the maximum size is a 32 bits integer.

Comment: Also the is nice alternative curl option for the progress callback, see here http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION.html

Comment: I've updated my post with an example.
@bodi0: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION option in the php cURL library... http://php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION function argument type are double, so you are probably casting these value to int somewhere in your code. and probably since your os is 32bit based architecture you are overflowing the int size limit. I would suggest you revise your code to avoid casting to int big double numbers.

Comment: Output: `int(-2147483648)`

Comment: i see, so the parameter is already an int. I am not sure there is anything you can do using this specific callback beside changing your os to a 64bits architecture that will increase the int limit of php to 9223372036854775807.

Comment: I'm running Debian 8 x64 already, could it be something else ? `uname -a` outputs the following: `Linux machinename 3.2.40 #5022 SMP Wed Jan 7 14:19:49 CST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: what is the values returned by PHP_INT_MAX (and PHP_INT_SIZE) ? if it's greater than 2147483648 I am not sure why you can't get the proper file size.

Comment: I found out my OS was 64bit but for some reason php5-fpm was 32bit, a clean install made the trick and now everything is working flawlessly. Thank you !